# Getting error when i am trying to save a sentence to text file on C

Tags: c

i am using windows 8. And my project is saved here :
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder
When I run main.c (not the project) says Source file not compiled!
That are the Errors I am getting when try to run the code:

```
1. gcc.exe main.o No such file or directory.
2. fata    no input files.
3.         recipe for target 'project.exe' failed
```

Why my code does not work?

```
main()
{
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
   fprintf(fp, "This is testing...\n");
   fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: There isn't enough information in the post to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. Provide sufficient information like how you are compiling the program.

Comment: There is not any more information this is full code and the errors

Comment: You're getting downvoted for posting garbage. None of us can see your C:\Users\Administrator\etc. location. `gcc` does not output "2. fata  no input files." , nor would it output stuff about "recipe" and "project.exe".  Also you may get downvoted because this question is about how to invoke gcc, but you titled it as if it was a problem with your code.

Comment: I changed the user to admin and the compiler D++ ran the code well!

Answer (score 1):

First, what is giving you those error messages?

Second, your program is not valid C.  `main()` needs to be declared with return type `int`.  For `FILE`, `fopen()`, `fprintf()`, and `fclose()` to be defined, you need to `#include <stdio.h>`.  And `main()` needs to return a value.

Try a program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
   fprintf(fp, "This is testing...\n");
   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

Then compile it using `gcc.exe main.c`.

Comment: In C, `main()` may not have a return type. And if `stdio.h` is not included, the error would be different.

Comment: WTF?  main() has been required to return int since at least C89.

Comment: `main()` must have a return type in C (and that return type must be `int`), unless you want to go into implementation-defined territory. It doesn't have to explicitly return a value, however, since it'll implicitly return `0` for you if you don't.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Obviously `main()` should return to the OS. But if it is not written explicitly, it will consider it `int` and return `0`.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: No, it won't. See C11 Section 5.1.2.2.1, which says that `main()` "shall be defined with a return type of `int`". "Shall" in the C standard, within the context of a constraint, means you either do it, or you've got undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Maybe with C11. But it will do fine with previous versions.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: Only if by "previous version", you mean K&R C.  C89, almost 25 years ago, required that `main` return `int`. Your favourite compiler might still support the old way, but that's implementation-dependent.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: Implicit `int` was removed fifteen years ago. And even though the standard allows for other implementation-defined ways, gcc, which is being used in this question, does not, as a matter of fact, define any alternatives.

Comment: In C90, `main()` was legal, and it means `int main()`

Comment: I changed the user to admin and the compiler D++ ran the code well!

Answer (score 0):

1) instead of:

```
 gcc.exe main.o
```

try:

```
 gcc.exe -o main.exe main.c
```

which means:

```
 Compile "main.c" and place the output into "main.exe"
```

---

```
 gcc.exe main.o
```

means:

```
 Compile "main.o"
```

However, the compiler cannot find a file named "main.o", so it generated the error:

```
fata    no input files.
        recipe for target 'project.exe' failed
```

Comment: When I run main.c (not the project) says Source file not compiled!

Comment: @user3579248 what do you mean by "run main.c" ?

Comment: I changed the user to admin and the compiler D++ ran the code well!